# How to locate temp.py and open in spyder on mac

Tags: python, spyder

I closed the temp.py spyder file by mistake and I wanted to recover it.
Where can it be found on a mac?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find it.
The file is located here:

/Users/bilal.mussa/.spyder-py3/temp.py